# convert List<> to map<>

Tags: flutter, dart, filter

how can I convert this List<> to Map<>?

```
extension Filter<T> on Stream<List<T>> {
  Stream<List<T>> filter(bool Function(T) where) =>
      map((items) => items.where(where).toList());
}
```

in order to use this filter in:

```
late final StreamData<Map<int, Habit>> habits;

 Stream<List<Habit>> get allHabits =>
      habits.stream.filter((habit) {
        final currentUser = _user;
        if (currentUser != null) {
          return habit.userId == currentUser.id;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need for your list are the values of the map, you can just transform the stream using the [map](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/map.html) method and extracting the values from each stream element using the [values](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map/values.html) property:

```
habits.stream  .map((m) => m.values.toList())  .filter((habit) {
```